# How to use pm2 startup command on Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, pm2

My question is the same as [How to use pm2 startup command on Debian platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506505/how-to-use-pm2-startup-command-on-debian-platform) but i need to make it start on Mac OS (darwin)

I only found a very bref documentation `$ pm2 startup <ubuntu|centos|gentoo|systemd>`

What can I do?

Comment: Told you [there](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/791) that you should have a look at **[launchd](http://launchd.info/)**. Put a `pm2.plist` file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` with the right informations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PM2 now has darwin option for startup, so running:

```
pm2 startup darwin
```

should work.

Also checkout this commit: [1. Make platform auto detecting. 2. Support darwin startup script.](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/commit/618e2da660e64d171b5d021dc40c434b96e88aa4#diff-90f0d7adce8e57b0cdc28b0c8a795d89) So right now, you can just call:

```
pm2 startup
```

and the script will recognise your OS.

NOTE: I'm currently having issues on Yosemite as the launchd gives me an error. You can find more info (and solution that works **for me**) here: [darwin startup script fix on yosemite #989](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/pull/989)

Also if you can test it in your environment and support this pull request, it would be great:)

Comment: i find it rather disturbing that either of those commands gives me a command to run which starts `sudo su -c` but that gives me the error `su: illegal option -- c`

Comment: MAC os Sierra. I just installed node i pm2. When I try any command that involves PM2 I get bash: pm2: command not found

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I haven't checked the pm2 for a while, because I moved to docker. But this looks like you don't have the pm2 installed (or at least the binary is not in the right place - maybe checking the $PATH could help)