# PM2 startup on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, pm2

I'm trying to set pm2 to auto start on Mac OS like this `pm2 startup`

However I keep getting this error: 
`env: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory`

I tried the suggestion from this page: [How to use pm2 startup command on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664282/how-to-use-pm2-startup-command-on-mac) But the even using this command I keep getting the same error: `pm2 startup darwin`

How can I get pm2 to startup automatically on Mac OS Catalina?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `pm2 startup` command it suggests you `PATH` variable. It seems that this variable contains spaces that causes this error. Try to get rid of `Fusion.app` part of it.

Comment: When I run `pm2 startup` it gives me this command to paste into terminal `sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u username --hp /Users/usernamev` When running this I get the above mentioned issue and I don't see where I need to remove the `Fusion.app` part

Comment: Just run `echo $PATH` and you will see it there. Seems that `pm2` can't handle your existing PATH variable. Just paste fixed one instead of `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on zored's answer, what's probably happening is that pm2 isn't generating the correct script because your `PATH` variable contains spaces (most likely "VMWare Fusion" in your case).

Run `echo $PATH`, clean it up by escaping the space character using a backslash (\), then manually paste the resulting `PATH` variable in pm2's generated startup script.

So basically instead of running a generated pm2 script like this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u <user> --hp <user_folder>
```

run something like this:

```
sudo env PATH=<your `echo $PATH` output with escaped spaces>:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u <user> --hp <user_folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wonder where the VMWare path parameter is set (and could be changed permanently):

/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public

The content of this file is added to the PATH environment